# Android app crashing when trying to load Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am trying to implement Google Maps V2 in my android apps while using fragments.

The code shows no errors however when i attempt to view the map, it crashes.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now so any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Map frag class:

```
public class mapFrag extends Fragment { 

MapView mMapView;
GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();//needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();



    //Perform any camera updates here

    return v;
}

}
```

layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.mapview 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/mapView">
</com.google.android.gms.maps.mapview>
```

logcat

```
 01-07 16:08:25.380: W/ImageView(1756):     at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-07 16:08:25.380: W/ImageView(1756):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 16:08:25.400: D/AndroidRuntime(1756): Shutting down VM
01-07 16:08:25.400: W/dalvikvm(1756): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a5a1f8)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.mapview
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.mapFrag.onCreateView(mapFrag.java:24)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4446)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.mapview
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-07 16:08:25.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1756):     ... 17 more
```

Comment: read this  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

Comment: you are using Google Maps wrong, read the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.mapview
```

It should be

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
```

not

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.mapview
```

Also you should read

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class. In particular, you must forward on the following methods:

```
onCreate(Bundle)
onResume()
onPause()
onDestroy()
onSaveInstanceState()
onLowMemory()
```

and you could refer this

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284)

Comment: Spot on Raghunandan, always something simple ey?

Comment: @c-bradz glad to help and red the MapView docs carefully. You are missing overriding some methods

Comment: I have life cycle methods implemented, was trying to save space so i left them out as it was unlikely the problem lay there. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you using any fragments. It should be:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```