# google maps v2 not working inside tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I had created an app showing google map. its was created by extending Activity class.
But Now i want the map to be shown onclick of a tab. This is my main activity class.
I have created 3 tabs. I want to show map on click of 1st tab.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs)
        {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));

        }

    }
```

Here is code of map fragment

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Here is code for fragment_map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MapActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/speedbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/map"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/speed_text"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/speedbar"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

when i execute above code it says

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity should extend `Activty` since you are using `MapFragment`.

Also you have `getSupportFragmentManager()`

If you targeting api level 11 and below you should use `SupportMapFragment` extend `FragmentActivity` and use Support Library

If not switch to `MapFragment`.

Also if you want to display the map inside a Fragment you should use `MapView`

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

You can refer this

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284)

Comment: cannot extend it with activty as am using tabs and fragments.

Comment: @user2504985 then use `SupportMapFragment`. I would suggest considering navigation drawer rather than tabs