# Fragment Tag in XML not Working in Fragment Class

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Here is the **Fragment Class** Calling an XML Which contains  tag

```
public class FragmentAbout extends Fragment {

    public FragmentAbout(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the **XML** file which contains  tag

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentTripPlan" > 


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_draw"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the **Log Trace**

```
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at com.c4a.itravellipaph.FragmentAbout.onCreateView(FragmentAbout.java:19)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4864)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
01-14 16:32:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(28486):    ... 19 more
```

How can i fix this one?
Big thanks in advance!
Fragment Tag in XML not Working in Fragment Class

Comment: show us the import statement  and the activity code

Comment: you want a map inside a fragment?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes sir. Im trying to convert my FragmentActivity Class Codes to Fragment Class

Comment: you should use a `MapView` for this purpose

Comment: so instead of <fragment> i will user MapView?

Comment: yes you should. use mapview

Answer (score 1):

You need to have

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Your activity must extend `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentAbout` is the fragment which is added to the container in activity xml ie FrameLayout

Also you should use `MapView`.You can find a similar example @

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284)

Comment: Thanks sir i will try this first before i ask again.