# Get Map view instance from a Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a `MainFragment` that consist of two fragments, a `MapFragment` and a `ListFragment` and this is its layout:

**MainFragment Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cups_black" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:name="com.citylifeapps.cups.fragments.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

</RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/black_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"         
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cups_black"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
    android:name="com.citylifeapps.cups.fragments.ListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button_close_full_map"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:background="@drawable/map_close_button_selector"
     android:text="@string/close"
      android:visibility="gone"
     android:textColor="@color/cups_black" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button_show_path"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"
     android:background="@drawable/map_close_button_selector"
     android:text="@string/show_path"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:textColor="@color/cups_black" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_navigate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/button_show_path"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/map_close_button_selector"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:text="@string/navigate"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:textColor="@color/cups_black" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

While the `MapFragment` just contains a `SupportMapFramgnet` in it,

**MapFragment Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraTargetLat="32.062505"
map:cameraTargetLng="34.778651"
map:cameraZoom="12"
map:mapType="normal"
map:uiZoomControls="false"
map:uiRotateGestures="true"
map:uiScrollGestures="true"
map:uiZoomGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="false" />
```

I want to add this fragment using the `FragmentManager` and then get the instance of the 
`mapview` which is basically the `SupportMapFragment`, so what I do is:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
    .add(R.id.content, MainFragment.create(), "Main Fragment")
    .commit();
```

to add this fragment to the `Activity`, and then I try to get the `mapview`:

```
smf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
```

But I get Null here.

**So the question is:** how can I get the instance of the map view in this case?

Comment: instead of supportmapfragment you should have a map view. i guess you want a map inside the fragment.

Comment: Actually it's an implementation I got inherited from other developer and most of the application is relies on this implementation so I can't just change it right now and besides fragment cascade is allowed. Isn't there a way to just get it's instance the way it's right now?

Comment: no there is not much to change intead of fragment in layout have a map view and initialize the map view in fragment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284. check this if it helps

Comment: I know there is not much work, but still I can changes it's implementation right now... I have to keep it as it is... So sorry, but this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the MapFragment is a child fragment, you need to use the childFragmentManager instead of SupportFragmentManager.

So you will need do something like:

```
MainFragment mainFragment = (MainFragment)getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content);

MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) mainFragment.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);

SupportMapFragment supportMap = (SupportMapFragment)mapFragment.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
```

That is untested code, but should point you in the right direction.

Something to note though: you seem to have an extra child fragment which you don't need.

The MapFragment fragment looks like its just a fragment that contains a SupportMapFragment.
You should try to avoid excess child fragments if they aren't necessary. Either replace the MapFragment with the SupportMapFragment entirely, or implement the mapview yourself in your MapFragment.

Comment: Didn't knew there is an ChildFragmentManager. I guess  that should put me in the right direction. Thanks I will test it and let you know. And Yes I know about the map, I see how this can be fixed.