# android map not running on the emulator

Tags: android

Is it possible to run the android map activity on the emulator? because I'm getting the error "this app won't run unless you update the Google play services"

My code is as follows :

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.example.googlev2map;
    import android.app.Activity;  
    import android.os.Bundle;  
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {  
         @Override  
         protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {  
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
              super.onCreate(arg0);  
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
         }  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"  
       android:layout_height="match_parent"  
       tools:context=".MainActivity" >  
       <fragment  
         android:id="@+id/fragment1"  
         android:layout_width="match_parent"  
         android:layout_height="match_parent"  
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />  
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlev2map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
        android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.googlev2map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlev2map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAy2ThskwG3Q9ArpZR_GvJP5_5IWfcEJhU"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
        </meta-data>
            <uses-library  
       android:name="com.google.android.maps"  
       android:required="true" />  

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you run on 4.3 coz it requires google play services on devices. its avaiable on emulator on 4.2.2 and higher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284

Comment: Make the googleApi emulator it will resolved

Comment: hey yes i m running on 4.3 also the target is google api (api level 18) even then it is giving me the error... pls help

Comment: @user3194074 is your emulator 4.3 and is it google API?

Comment: hey its platform 4.3 and target google api (level 18)

Comment: @user3194074 it will work fine. you won't get that message. If oyu are getting that message that means there is no google play services on emulator. test it on a real device

Comment: has it anything to do with the gpu? do i need to enable it??

Answer (score 0):

```
 this app wont run unless you update the Google play services
```

Google map requires google play services.

To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

1. A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
2. The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

So if you still get the message "this app wont run unless you update the Google play services" it is clear that the device on which you are trying to run does not have google play services installed. So you need to test on a real device that has google play servies installed

Comment: i m running it on platform 4.3 and target google apis(api level 18)