# ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file for Map-V2

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I m trying to integrate a map-V2 into my application and getting the error "This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!" Please help me!

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that this is due to non existence of google play services in emulator

If I am right then please follow this answer [Running Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040185/running-google-maps-v2-on-android-emulator)

may this could help you

Comment: but i have imported google play services in my project

Comment: Importing means your giving support of MAP-V2 in your app but your emulator doesn't have capability of handling Google Service

Comment: Do you get the exact screen in your emulator as displayed in the above URL

Comment: when i create a new avd it does not show the HARDWARE option

Comment: try to run your app in device and check whether this problem also exist their?

Comment: actually the problem is that this map is a part of our project and we need to display it on an emulator. so if you could help?

Comment: I tried it what I think it could be but before looking at the actual thing I can't predict the problem

Comment: I want to tell you the same thing that raghunandan said in your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140747/android-map-not-running-on-the-emulator

Comment: also when i am trying to add my google play services in my project properties it is not getting added( showing a red cross)

Comment: increase your reputation above 20 so people can chat with you

Comment: answer some question other's and editing the question or answer if some one accepts your answer or up-vote your question or ans your will get repu points. Like you get 5 points by my up-vote to your question