# error parsing:unbound prefix exception

Tags: android, google-maps, exception

This code shows unbound exception,i tried all combinations.. cant ressolve !!

```
    <com.google.android.maps:MapView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
     android.apikey="AIzaSyDIqLvjKi_VM7nT1DUSTzIeKDTuzPGFqrQ"/>
```

The entire code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  
     <com.google.android.maps:MapView
      android:id="@+id/map1"    
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
      android:apikey="AIzaSyDIqLvjKi_VM7nT1DUSTzIeKDTuzPGFqrQ"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your full xml layout. why is the api key in `MapView`?

Comment: also post your java codes and manifest. suspect more mistkaes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in your root element of xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  
     <com.google.android.maps.MapView // :MapView is .MapView
      android:id="@+id/map1"    
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>    
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Also

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="api key"/>
// android.apikey
```

must be in application tag of manifest file

You can find an example

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284)

Reference

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 2):

You defined wrong Mapview `<com.google.android.maps:MapView` you added. `:` before `MapView` and that is wrong. You must replace `:` with `.`.
it's like below:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

and also add API key into application tag in manifest like below:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="your api key"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace **android.apikey** with **android:apikey**

May it helps..