# The method getMap() is undefined

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I get "The method getMap() is undefined for the type" on the following code. Why? 
I have added the Google-Play-Services library.

I have also created this exact same code in an Activity instead of a Fragment and then I didn't get this error. But I neew to use this inside a Fragment

Karta.java:

```
package nu.sluggo.testapp.foretagsinfo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Karta extends Fragment{



    public static Karta newInstance() {
        Karta f = new Karta();
        return f;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.karta, container, false);
        return v;

    }   

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

    final LatLng BUTIKPLATS = new LatLng(57.873873, 11.974995);

    GoogleMap karta;
        karta  = ((Karta) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kontaktVisaFragment)).getMap();

        karta.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BUTIKPLATS).title("Vita Fläckens Blommor"));
        karta.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BUTIKPLATS, 17);
        karta.animateCamera(update);
    }
    }
```

Comment: why not extends `SupprorMapFragment` or `MapFragment` instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284. check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Karta` does not `extends` `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`; `getMap()` is only present in those classes (when dealing with `Fragments`. You will need to either make `Karta` extends one of the two (depending on your `minSdkVersion`) or use:

```
GoogleMap karta  = ((`SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.kontaktVisaFragment)).getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I declare as a global variable

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment
```

and then in my onCreate() or onCreateView() call

```
    mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
```

if you user SupportMapFragment in your Java implementation make sure to use the same in XML

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```