# Crash for inflating class

Tags: android, android-layout, maps, runtime-error, mapsforge

I am new in android, I want to implement action bar sliding, i read tutorials and write this. in program, i used a framelayout, the framelayout fill with mapsforge, but progrma in runtime has error. why? if i remove fragment and transaction fragment, the program runs good.

```
public class ShowSlidingMenu extends FragmentActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private ListView listView;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

MapView mapView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sliding);

    Fragment fragment=new MapFragmentTest();
    FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.mapView, fragment).commit();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(5, -1)));

    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
             this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            displayView();
        }

    });
}

//remove onCreateOptionsMenu()

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;

    //remove action bar settings 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//remove onPrepareOptionsMenu()

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mTitle=title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void displayView(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hahaha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

MapFragmentTest

```
public class MapFragmentTest extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

log:

```
01-27 09:08:48.185: E/AndroidRuntime(13176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 09:08:48.185: E/AndroidRuntime(13176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {org.example.sendandreceivesms/org.example.slidingmenubar.ShowSlidingMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView
```

Comment: Make sure you have added library in your build path.

Comment: Can you show your imports of `MapFragmentTest` class ?

Comment: import org.example.sendandreceivesms.R;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView
```

to

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
```

Since you mentioned in the comment that you use mapsforge library follow

http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapView

Comment: but i use mapsforge class. why i should i change this?

Comment: @user3209380 you are using mapview. i guess you want map inside a fragment. so use mapview as suggested

Comment: @user3209380 do refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284

Comment: I want to fill FrameLayout with mapsforge. what u suggest?

Comment: @user3209380 do as suggested and use `MapView`.

Comment: i use google mapView but i have same error. and i cant understand why i should use google mapview instead of mapsforge?

Comment: @user3209380 see the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284

Comment: @user3209380 and have you referenced google play services library project?

Comment: @user3209380 no idea about mapsforg library. I only follow the docs. If you want to follow the docs and then do as i suggested

Comment: @user3209380 pls tag your question properly so that you do not mislead others add mapsfor tag/ i edited and added the same

Answer (score 0):

have you declared required permissions in manifest.xml file for display map.

according to documentation you should add-

```
The map library requires only one permission for writing cached images to the external storage (typically the phones SD card). Add the following line to your applications AndroidManifest.xml file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and use below code to display map-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.File;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;

public class HelloMapView extends MapActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMapFile(new File("/sdcard/path/to/mapfile.map"));
    setContentView(mapView);
}
}
```

Comment: yeah i add  '    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />'

Comment: I want map set in FrameLayout and for this i used Fragment, where i used this code? i set map in setContentView() method . sorry for my questions. Thanks

Comment: but i think with this, my problem not solved. becuase when i trace program, in onCreateView() method in inflater.inflate(), the program crash :( when i want shows map with activity again the program crash. what is the problem?

Comment: are you sure that you added mapsforge-map library.please recheck it.

Comment: yeah i add this to libs folder. I add your code to program but again, i have same error :(

Comment: when i want shows map without fragment, map shows but with fragment i have error

Comment: error is in first my post in log: 01-27 09:08:48.185: E/AndroidRuntime(13176): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {org.example.sendandreceivesms/org.example.slidingmenubar.ShowSlidingMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView

Comment: see these two link here is your solution:  http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/issues/detail?id=177
and
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/7U_9zfmwd-s

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error message and I had fixed it with the followings:

- Add all the jar files (which includes `mapsforge-core-0.5.0.jar`, `mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar`, `mapsforge-map-android-0.5.0.jar`, `mapsforge-map-reader-0.5.0.jar`) and check it in android java build path configuration (Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export)
- Add this line to the classes before the map or add it in Application class `AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(this.getApplication());`
  If this is not added, it will clash according to their [documentation](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Android-App.md)

Hope that the above helps :)