# Displaying map in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I have a master class which creates two fragment classes.  One of them is MapDisplay().java

I want to display a map in this class.  Here is my code for MapDisplay()

```
public class MapDisplay extends Fragment implements OnMapClickListener{
    private GoogleMap googlemap;
    LatLng GAN = new LatLng(34.4305556,74.9250000);

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maplayout, container, false);


        try
        {
            if(googlemap==null)
            {
                 googlemap=  
            ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2)).getMap();
            googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googlemap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            }
            if(googlemap!=null)
            {

            Marker m = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(GAN).title("Gangbal")); 
            m.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(GAN, 15));
            googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10),2000,null);
            googlemap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WELL! HELLO THERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }       
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
        Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
        args1.putParcelable("LOCATION", GAN);
        Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(),FullScreenMap.class);
        a.putExtra("bundle", args1);
        a.putExtra("title", "Gangbal");
        startActivity(a);

    }
}
```

And here's my XML layout file maplayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

This class however, doesn't display the map I want to.  Just a world map with no markers.  Also clicking on this map doesn't work.

I'm creating the MapDisplay() fragment class in another class

```
    FragmentPagerAdapter tabadapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.tabpager);
pager.setAdapter(tabadapter);

    class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
     public Fragment getItem(int m) {
    switch(m)
    {
    case 0:
        return new MapDisplay();
    case 1:
        return new Description();
    }
    return null;
}

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.length;
    }
```

}

So I guess MapDisplay() should extend Fragment, right??
What am I doing wrong?  Please help!

Comment: Have you tried to extend MapFragment instead of Fragment ?

Comment: You are doing it completely wrong, You need to extend `MapFragment` instead of `Fragment`, you also should not be using `SupportMapFragment` when you are using `MapFragment` in your xml and you do not get a Fragment by id in a fragment, you only do that in an activity

Comment: @tyczj.  Check the edited question.  I'm creating fragment classes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `MapView` or your fragment should extend `MapFragment`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

So have the below in `maplayout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Fragment

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maplayout, container, false);
MapView  mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap map = mapView.getMap();
```

You also need to check the availability of google play services which is not shown here.

Note:

Users of this class (MapView) must forward all the life cycle methods from the `Activity` or `Fragment` containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class. In particular, you must forward on the following methods:

```
onCreate(Bundle)
onResume()
onPause()
onDestroy()
onSaveInstanceState()
onLowMemory()
```

You can check the answer @

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin)