# Null pointer exception using maps API2 android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, maps, fragment

I am integrating maps in my application.
The map is also shown in the application.
But I am not able to find its view.

This is my fragment class.

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment,
                container, false);
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 //         googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 //         googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I am getting the null pointer exception..

Log cat is as follows:

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main

     : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.herobike.main/com.herobike.service.SearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.herobike.service.SearchActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(SearchActivity.java:52)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
```

Line No: 52 is

```
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

This is xml of fragment

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sc_10"
tools:context="com.herobike.main.SearchActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
```

What needs to be updated here?

Comment: Have you define that in your xml ??

Comment: You are using map inside fragments ???

Comment: can you just post your xml...

Comment: check and try the solution and see the explanation.

Comment: got the explanation @Shink ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout file instead of `MapFragment` you need to write `SupportMapFragment` as you have already accessed it using `SupportMapFragment` .So change it as below:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
```

Also initialize your map as below:

```
 googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                    .getMap();
```

Comment: @Shink this still does not solve the problem coz you want map inside of a fragment. In any case if that was the problem you should get a classcastexcpetion

Comment: @GrIsHu he will face problem later coz he mentions that he wants map inside a fragment.

Comment: @Raghunandan I am not getting any exception. And the map is working fine.

Comment: @Shink good luck. I don't think you have a map inside of a fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan the map is inside the fragment only

Comment: @Shink you have a fragment inside of it you have a SupportMapFragment. Nested Fragments?. By the look of your code it does not look like that. Any way do check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin and that's why i doubt you have a map fragment inside of a fragment. Even if that was the case you should get classcastexception casting `MapFragment` to `SupportMapFragment`. But you say you got NPE and that does not make sense to me

Comment: @Raghunandan Why don't you just accept as shink has already said that his problem is already solved. Do you have issue with my correct answer. Please don't show that you are upset that your answer is not correct. This kind of arguments doesn't make sense as the problem is already solved. So there is nothing to argue for that.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have referenced the id of fragment right.

```
public final GoogleMap getMap ()

Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this fragment.

Returns
the GoogleMap. Null if the view of the fragment is not yet ready.
```

> This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also
>   happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play
>   services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone
>   through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this
>   method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

It is better to chekc the availability of google play services before initializing map object.

Edit:

> yes inside fragment

What you have done

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Its a `MapFragment`.

But you have

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

which is wrong

What you need to do

So you want map inside a fragment. So you need to extend `MapFragment` instead of `Fragment` or you should use `MapView`

Check the below

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin)

Answer (score 0):

pLease try this ,let me know if any concern

```
if (googleMap == null)
            {
                googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_history)).getMap();
        }
```

Comment: @Shink Please try at once in onResume method

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and make the following changes in your layout

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use supportmapfragment :-

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: You are using MapFragment in your xml and inflating it with SupportMapFragment, that's why causing error.