# I keep getting a nullPointerException whenever I call the getMap()

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

No matter what I do my code seems to crash at the getMap(). I have tried adjusting my code almost everywhere. I have created this app before but due to a computer crash I had to rebuild. some of my code.Now it crashes. 
My Main code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class FishFishSpotActivity extends Activity{

    public static final String XCORD = "xcord";
public static final String YCORD = "ycord";
public static final String NOTE = "note";
public static final String SAVED = "saved";
public static final String ID = "id";
TextView XCord= null;
TextView YCord= null;
TextView Note= null;
int Id = 0;
Boolean Saved = null;
private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fish_fish_spot);

    initializeMap();

    }

    protected void onStart(){
        map.isMyLocationEnabled();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

        return false;

    }

    public void onMapClick(LatLng point){
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
    }

    public void onMarkerClick(Marker marker){

    }

    public static void SpotSaved(boolean saved, String A){

    }

    private void initializeMap() 
    {
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (map == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Here is my manafist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Nick.fishfishspot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<permission 
    android:name="com.Nick.fishfishspot.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.Nick.fishfishspot.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="key is here"/>
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="go" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/x_cord"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/y_cord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/x_cord"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/x_cord"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/x_cord"
    android:ems="10" />
```

This is the error:

```
 05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.Nick.fishfishspot/com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
   05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    at com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity.initializeMap(FishFishSpotActivity.java:76)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    at com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity.onCreate(FishFishSpotActivity.java:38)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    at    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    05-05 22:44:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(24604):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in application tag of manifest

`getMap()` can return null. You can check the availability of google play services before initializing `GoogleMap` object

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying
>   maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists.
>   This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view;
>   however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this
>   depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a
>   GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

Also `tools:context="com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity$PlaceholderFragment"` gives an hint that your `MapFragment` belongs to fragment while you initialize it in Activity.

You need to extend `MapFragment` or use `MapView` in Fragment layout if you want map inside a fragment.

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin)

Comment: I would like to use 'MapFragment' however I get a new list of errors '05-05 23:54:22.802: E/AndroidRuntime(4964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Nick.fishfishspot/com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Nick.fishfishspot.FishFishSpotActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity'

Comment: @user3606473 its a classcastexception. post the updated code and the new stacktrace editing your post