# Maps in Fragment[IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id]

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

So, I have `two fragments` (`F1` and `F2`), `F1` contains the `maps fragment`, `F2` contains some data. so when i load fragment `F1`, the map load perfectly, but when i go to fragment `F2` and come back to fragment one via button click(which loads the fragment again), i get the following error:

```
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at com.porcupyne.mumbaifoodlovers.MapsFragment.onCreateView(MapsFragment.java:46)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f08006a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4740)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
06-03 16:13:56.227: E/AndroidRuntime(7748):     ... 19 more
```

Following is my code for the map fragment(F1)
`MapsFragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the java code:
`MapsFragment.java`

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
double latitude;
double longitude;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
Context context;
boolean isNetworkAvailable = false;
Location location;

public MapsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container,
            false);

    try {
        initializeMap();

        LatLng pos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(pos)
                .title("Fishork")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
        MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(18.90370, 72.81314))
                .title("Zaffran")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

        CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions().center(pos).radius(2000)
                .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")).strokeWidth(5)
                .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#25f67f21"));

        CircleOptions circle1 = new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(18.90370, 72.81314)).radius(1000)
                .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")).strokeWidth(5)
                .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#25f67f21"));

        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker1);
        googleMap.addCircle(circle);
        googleMap.addCircle(circle1);

        CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(10).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "MSG: " + e);
    }

    return rootView;
}

private void initializeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsFragment.this.getActivity(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

Can someone please help ?! Thank you.

Comment: Are you loading same `MapsFragment.xml` into your `Fragmten2`?

Comment: Use MapView. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/20971284#20971284. Looks like you have nested fragments. Do you want that?

Comment: @SimplePlan: no ive a different frame_container where i load both fragments F1 and F2.

Comment: @VarunBarve u got any solutoin for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public MapsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Let the mapFragment draw itself and then you return this view later at the bottom.
    View mapView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);


    /*View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container,
            false);*/

    try {
        initializeMap();

        LatLng pos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(pos)
                .title("Fishork")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
        MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(18.90370, 72.81314))
                .title("Zaffran")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

        CircleOptions circle = new CircleOptions().center(pos).radius(2000)
                .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")).strokeWidth(5)
                .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#25f67f21"));

        CircleOptions circle1 = new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(18.90370, 72.81314)).radius(1000)
                .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")).strokeWidth(5)
                .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#25f67f21"));

        //Get instance to this googleMap
        googleMap = this.getMap();


        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker1);
        googleMap.addCircle(circle);
        googleMap.addCircle(circle1);

        CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(10).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "MSG: " + e);
    }

    return mapView;
}
```