# How to add a Google Map in a dialog. Both dialog and map doesn't show up

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-dialog, android-maps-v2

I want to create e dialog/alertDialog where a google map is shown. I've create a dialog and inflate the layout where there is a map view but the app crash/and give me the following error:

```
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): Process: it.sii.android.jobaroundu, PID: 1716
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@52d5318c is not valid; is your activity running?
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:536)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at it.sii.android.jobaroundu.PaginaRisultati$MyExpandableListAdapter$2.onClick(PaginaRisultati.java:300)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-15 10:56:32.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1716):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my activity:

```
public class PaginaRisultati extends ExpandableListActivity {
    //Initialize variables
        private static final String STR_CHECKED = " has Checked!";
        private static final String STR_UNCHECKED = " has unChecked!";
        private int ParentClickStatus=-1;
        private int ChildClickStatus=-1;
        private ArrayList<Parent> parents;
        private String username;
        private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
        private String regione;
        private String provincia;
        private String[] tag;
        private final static int MAP_MESSAGE_ID = 1;
        private final static int PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID = 1;
        private String posizione;
        private String azienda;
        final Context context = this;
        MapView mMapView;
        GoogleMap mMap;
        Marker mark;
        Bundle bundle;
        double lat;
        double lng;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bundle=savedInstanceState;

        //setContentView(R.layout.prova_risultati);
        MyDBHelper dbHelper2 = new MyDBHelper(this,"JobAroundU_DB", null, 1);
        final SQLiteDatabase db2;


        Intent dati = getIntent();

        String pkg = getPackageName();
        regione = dati.getStringExtra(pkg+".Regione");
        provincia = dati.getStringExtra(pkg+".Provincia");
        tag = dati.getStringArrayExtra(pkg+".Tag");
        username=dati.getStringExtra(pkg+".Username");
        GetAnnunciThread gat= new GetAnnunciThread(regione, provincia, tag);
        gat.run();
        gat.start();
        try {
            gat.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        //controllo se risultati esistono --> se non esistono stampo messaggio di errore

        Resources res = this.getResources();
        Drawable devider = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent);
        Drawable group_indicator = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.group_indicator);
        // Set ExpandableListView values 
        getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(group_indicator);
        getExpandableListView().setDivider(devider);
        getExpandableListView().setChildDivider(devider);
        getExpandableListView().setDividerHeight(15);
        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());

        //Creating static data retrived from the result of the thread in arraylist
         parents = gat.annuncitrovati;

        if (parents.isEmpty()) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
                ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.immagine);
                image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_25761));
                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ToastTV);
                text.setText("La ricerca non ha prodotto risultati!!");

                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
                //richiamo activity precedente (la pagina di ricerca del lavoro)

        }

        db2=dbHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
        //metto nella view e stampo a video 
        // Check for ExpandableListAdapter object
        if (this.getExpandableListAdapter() == null)        {
                    //Create ExpandableListAdapter Object
                    final MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
                    // Set Adapter to ExpandableList Adapter
                    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                     // Refresh ExpandableListView data 
                    ((MyExpandableListAdapter)getExpandableListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

    }




    private class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        protected SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper2 =new MyDBHelper(PaginaRisultati.this,"JobAroundU_DB", null, 1);

        public MyExpandableListAdapter()
        {
            // Create Layout Inflator
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PaginaRisultati.this);
        }


        // This Function used to inflate parent rows view

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
                View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
        {
            final Parent parent = parents.get(groupPosition);

            // Inflate grouprow.xml file for parent rows
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, parentView, false); 

            // Get grouprow.xml file elements and set values
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(parent.getPosizione());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVData)).setText(parent.getAzienda());
            ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_tag);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_21039);
            //ImageView rightcheck=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightcheck);
            final ImageButton imgbtt = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            imgbtt.setFocusable(false);

            //metto stellina colorata se l'annuncio  tra i preferiti e se lo  metto a false la possibilità di inseririlo tra di essi, evitando cosi' doppioni
            SQLiteDatabase db2=dbHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
            String sqlPref = "SELECT idDBJobs FROM MyPreferences";
            Cursor cursor = db2.rawQuery(sqlPref, null);
            boolean prefAnn=false;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                if(cursor.getString(0).equals(parent.getId())){
                    imgbtt.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_star);
                    prefAnn=true;
                }
            }

            if(prefAnn==false){
                imgbtt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("preferred job announce", "aggiungi ai preferiti INIZIO ");
                        //preferiti e ricerche recenti sono nel DB SQLite dell'app
                            int num = Integer.parseInt(parent.getId());

                            String sqlMyPreference="INSERT INTO  MyPreferences (Position, Firm, Description, idDBJobs ) VALUES ('"+parent.getPosizione()+"', '"+parent.getAzienda()+"', '"+parent.getChildren().get(0).getDescrizione()+"', "+num+");";

                            SQLiteDatabase db2=dbHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
                            db2.execSQL(sqlMyPreference);   
                            db2.close();
                            Log.i("preferred job announce", "Aggiunto " +parent.getPosizione()+" nell'azienda  "+parent.getAzienda()+" ai preferiti");
                            imgbtt.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_star);
                        }

                });
            }

            return convertView;
        }


        // This Function used to inflate child rows view
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
                View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
        {
            final Parent parent = parents.get(groupPosition);
            final Child child = parent.getChildren().get(childPosition);

            // Inflate childrow.xml file for child rows
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, parentView, false);

            // Get childrow.xml file elements and set values
            /***INDIRIZZO***/
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVTags)).setText(child.getIndirizzo());
            ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_tag);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_14236);

            Button b0 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            if(child.getIndirizzo().equals("Indirizzo NON presente")){
                b0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            b0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //recupero indirizzo
                    String indirizzodaconvertire= ""+child.getIndirizzo();
                    azienda=""+parent.getAzienda();
                    posizione = ""+parent.getPosizione();

                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    //final View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_mapview, null);
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main_mapview);
                    mMapView = (MapView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mymapview);
                    mMapView.onCreate(bundle);  
                        MapsInitializer.initialize(context);

                        if (mMap == null) {
                            mMap = mMapView.getMap();
                                     if (mMap != null) {
                                }
                        }


                        TextView tv= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addressName);
                        tv.setText(indirizzodaconvertire);
                        searchPlace(indirizzodaconvertire);

                            dialog.setTitle("MAPPA!!!");
                            dialog.show();




                        //}
                //  });



                    /*  Intent i = new Intent(PaginaRisultati.this, SeeAddress.class);
                i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Address", indirizzodaconvertire);
                    i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Azienda",azienda);
                    i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Posizione", posizione);

                    i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Regione", regione);
                    i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Provincia", provincia);
                    i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Tag", tag);
                    i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Username", username);

                    startActivity(i);*/

                    //replaceContentView("aa", i);
                }

            });
            /***LUOGO LAVORO ****/
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVLoc_prov)).setText(child.getLuogoLavoro());

            /***DESCRIZIONE ****/
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVLoc_regione)).setText(child.getDescrizione());
            ImageView image2=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageLoc);
            image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_16301);

            /***STIPENDIO ****/
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TWStipendio)).setText(child.getStipendio());
            ImageView image3=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageStipendio);
            image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_21213);

            /***CANDIDATURA CELLULARE ****/
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TWCandCell)).setText(child.getCandidaturaCellulare());
            ImageView image4=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageCandCell);
            image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_14583);

            /**** EMAIL ****/
            TextView tv= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TWMail);
            tv.setText(child.getEmail());

            ImageView image5=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageMail);
            image5.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_98);
            Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);


            /*** BOTTONE YOUTUBE ***/
            Button b1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(child.getYT().equals("Video non presente")){
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
                        ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.immagine);
                        image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.youtube_notfind));
                        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ToastTV);
                        text.setText("Video non presente!");

                        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.setView(layout);
                        toast.show();
                    }else{
                        //Intent i = new Intent(PaginaRisultati.this, YTActivity.class);
                        Intent i = new Intent(PaginaRisultati.this, YouTubeDialogActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(getPackageName()+".YTV", child.getYT());
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }

            });
            /***BOTTONE visibile solo se possible inviare candidatura via cell****/
            Button b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.candidati);
            if(child.getCandidaturaCellulare().equals("Candidatura via cellulare possibile")==false){
                //nascondo bottone se non e' possibile inviare candidatura
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


            //CODICE PER INVIARE LA MAIL --> apre  nuova activity con dati del lavoro--> email destinatario gia' inserita, allegato da scegliere e messaggio da editare
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    PersonalDataThread t3 = new PersonalDataThread(username);
                    t3.run();
                    t3.start();

                    try {
                        t3.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR -PERSONALDATA", ""+e.toString());
                    }
                    Intent ii= new Intent (PaginaRisultati.this, MailActivity.class);
                        ii.putExtra(getPackageName()+".EmailReceiver", child.getEmail());
                        ii.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Posizione", parent.getPosizione());
                        ii.putExtra(getPackageName()+".NomeUser", t3.nomeDB);
                        ii.putExtra(getPackageName()+".CognomeUser", t3.cognomeDB);
                        ii.putExtra(getPackageName()+".EmailSender", t3.mailDB);
                        ii.putExtra(getPackageName()+".Azienda", parent.getAzienda());
                    startActivity(ii);
                }

            });

            return convertView;
        }


        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            //Log.i("Childs", groupPosition+"=  getChild =="+childPosition);
            return parents.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
        }

        //Call when child row clicked
        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            /****** When Child row clicked then this function call *******/

            if( ChildClickStatus!=childPosition)
            {
               ChildClickStatus = childPosition;

            }  

            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
        {
            int size=0;
            if(parents.get(groupPosition).getChildren()!=null)
                size = parents.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
            return size;
        }


        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
        {
            Log.i("Parent", groupPosition+"=  getGroup ");

            return parents.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount()
        {
            return parents.size();
        }

        //Call when parent row clicked
        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
        {
            ParentClickStatus=groupPosition;
            if(ParentClickStatus==0)
                ParentClickStatus=-1;
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged()
        {
            // Refresh List rows
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return ((parents == null) || parents.isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }


        /******************* Checkbox Checked Change Listener ********************/

        private final class CheckUpdateListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener
        {
            private final Parent parent;

            private CheckUpdateListener(Parent parent)
            {
                this.parent = parent;
            }
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                Log.i("onCheckedChanged", "isChecked: "+isChecked);
                parent.setChecked(isChecked);

                ((MyExpandableListAdapter)getExpandableListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                final Boolean checked = parent.isChecked();
            }
        }
        /***********************************************************************/


        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


    }

    public void searchPlace(String inputName) {
        final String s = inputName;
        Thread searchThread = new Thread("SerachThread") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message message = mapHandler.obtainMessage();

                String addressToSearch = s;
                addressToSearch = addressToSearch.replace(" ", "%20");

                JSONObject addressInfo = getAddressInfo(addressToSearch);

                try
                {
                    if (addressInfo != null && addressInfo.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                        message.obj = addressInfo;
                        mapHandler.sendMessage(message);

                    }
                    else
                        mapHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MAP_MESSAGE_ID);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    mapHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MAP_MESSAGE_ID);
                }

                //dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);            
                }
        };
        //showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID);
        //searchThread.run();

        searchThread.start();

        while(searchThread.isAlive()){
        }


    }

    private final Handler mapHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg!=null && msg.obj!=null){
                JSONObject addressInfo = (JSONObject)msg.obj;

                try{
                     lng = ((JSONArray)addressInfo.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");
                     lat = ((JSONArray)addressInfo.get("results")).getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");                     
                     MarkerOptions mo= new MarkerOptions();
                     mo.position(new LatLng(lat,lng))
                     .title(posizione)
                     .snippet(azienda)
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lng), 16.0f));
                    mark = mMap.addMarker(mo);
                    //onMarkerClick(mark);
                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker){
                              // This causes the marker to bounce into position when it is clicked.
                            if (marker.equals(mark)) {
                                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                                Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
                                Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(new LatLng(lat,lng));
                                startPoint.offset(0, -100);
                                final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
                                final long duration = 2000;
                                final Interpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator();
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                                        float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
                                        double lng1 = t * lng + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
                                        double lat1 = t * lat + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
                                        marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat1, lng1));
                                        if (t < 1.0) {
                                            // Post again 16ms later.
                                            handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            // We return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
                            // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
                            // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
                            return false;
                        }

                    });


                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Found nothing. Retry!", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Found nothing. Retry!", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    };





    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG_ID:
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this,
                    ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setTitle("GeocodingTest");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Searching...");
            return progressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static JSONObject getAddressInfo(String sAddress) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + sAddress + "&sensor=false");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            Log.d("Google Geocoding Response", stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }   


    /**
    //CARICO LA NUOVA ACTIVITY ALL'INTERNO DEL CORPO DEL TAB
        public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
            this.getApplicationContext()
            View view =this.getApplication().getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ff",
                    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                    .getDecorView();
            this.setContentView(view);
        }
    */
    }
```

This is the layout inflated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/addressName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:inputType="text"></TextView>
        <!-- <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:text="Search" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="searchPlace"
            android:layout_weight="3"></Button> -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mymapview"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp" 

        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        map:cameraTargetLat="45.070139"
        map:cameraTargetLng="7.6700892"
        map:cameraZoom="5"

        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiRotateGestures="false"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="false"
        map:uiZoomControls="true"
        map:uiZoomGestures="false"
        >

   </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Where is the mistake(s)? Please, can you help me and correct my code?

Thanks

M

Comment: Use a DialogFragment and use mapview

Answer (score 1):

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@52d5318c is not valid; is your activity running?
```

You need to have

```
Context context; //declare it as an instance variable
```

Then in onCreate

```
context = this; // initialize in onCreate. this refers to activity context
```

Activity Context is available once Activity is created.

For the maps you can use a `DialogFragment`

Comment: thanks... I don't know how to use DialogFragment and a Map in a fragment since I'm new to Android programming... can you help me posting some code?

Comment: @user3649608 i can't post the whole code. I will post a link where map is displayed in a Fragment. Similarly do it for `DialogFragment`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin