# Error inflating class fragment Caused by: Duplicate id 0x7f06003e..... with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

i try to display map in my application, for first time I launch my application, everything is going fine untill I'm going to another page that display Map too.
this is my code :

```
public class PKN_Frag_SummaryKabupaten extends Fragment{
private GoogleMap map;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        View Sum_Kab = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modul2_kabupaten, container,
                false);
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(MAP_PUPI, 15));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(0), 2000, null);
return Sum_Kab;

    }
    private GoogleMap getGoogleMap() {
         if (map == null && getActivity() != null && getActivity().getFragmentManager()!= null) {
             MapFragment smf = (MapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                if (smf != null) {
                    map = smf.getMap();
                }
            }
            return map;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() 
     {
        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

and this is my code for map :

```
 <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and this is what logcat said :

```
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #251: Error inflating class fragment
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at id.go.kpp.aplikasipupi.pkn.PKN_Frag_SummaryKabupaten.onCreateView(PKN_Frag_SummaryKabupaten.java:115)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1401)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #251: Duplicate id 0x7f06003e, tag null, or parent id 0x7f06003d with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4819)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-14 14:21:20.186: E/AndroidRuntime(29586):    ... 20 more
```

I don't know where is my fault, because when I run in with `extend Activity`, there is no error or something wrong, is there anyone can help me?

**UPDATE**

this is what happen after I'm using MapView

[image]

Comment: Third line is `'@Override` ?

Comment: A Fragment within a Fragment. Instead use Mapview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin

Comment: @Raghunandan I've implement your method using MapView, but why my MapView doesn't display anything?

Comment: @NenMa what do you see on screen

Comment: @Raghunandan see on My update Question, that's what display on my application

Comment: @NenMa Check your api key in the google play console. The code in the link posted is allright. Re-generate the api key.

Comment: @Raghunandan when I'm Using `<fragment........class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>` this is display very well, am I must to re-generate my api key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57255/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-nenma).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by following Raghunandad's answer by adding MapView in my fragment as is stated in this answer  stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/. I also had a blank mapview at first because I did not set mapView.onResume(); mapView.onDestroy(); and mapView.onLowMemory();

I hope it will work for you too.

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```