# Using onbackpressed() while using fragment containing map fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am working on a project where there are many fragments connected to a fragment manager.I want to implement onbackpressed method in my fragmentactivity so that i can go back to the previous fragement.

The onbackpressedcode is shown below:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

                int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

                if (count == 0) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                    //additional code
                } else {


                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }

            }
```

The issue is that there is a supportmapfragment in one of the fragment.There is a listview in that fragment .When i click an item in the listview it takes me to another fragment which contains details.When i press back i get an illegalstateexception as shown below:

```
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at com.igloo.fragments.ViewjobsFragment.onCreateView(ViewjobsFragment.java:123)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1527)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:494)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at com.igloo.marinaretail.UserMain.onBackPressed(UserMain.java:476)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1898)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1280)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2078)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1705)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2626)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2601)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1873)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f06005e, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
10-27 13:31:26.039: E/AndroidRuntime(15458):    ... 26 more
```

How do i prevent the above issue on pressing back.

Also in the ondestroy method of the fragment containing the map i have the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f.isResumed()){ 
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**How do i fix the back pressed issue?**

Is there a way to check if the previous fragment in the stack is the fragment containing the supportmap?

Comment: Try this it helps me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin/41381507#41381507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following code in the fragment class that contains map:

```
public void onDestroyView() 
 {
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

as i see your comment i think you just initialize your googleMap just for time that it's null, you have something like following code,

```
if (googleMap == null)
{

   // initialize Map
}
```

remove if part and initialize your map.

Comment: I tried the above,the problem is that when i press back pressed, i get an empty map without the pins and data i retrieve from server.

Comment: But the code for getting the location is not linked to initialising the map.

Comment: Is there a way to run the code for that fragment freshly/

Comment: hooom, i don't know but i had same problem and i've fixed that with this two part code,

Comment: thanks..i had the sampe problem and this solution works!