# Android error when inflating map fragment when using maps api

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity

I get a Error inflating class fragment when using the google maps api and displaying it on a fragment. It gets displayed in a swipe tab, but that should not be the problem. Here is my code:

Activity:

```
public class MapActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapView = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Stacktrace:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
        at com.example.MapActivity.onCreateView(MapActivity.java:15)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2881)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
```

The line it shows the error is the following one:
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);`

Answer (score 0):

You `Activity` class extends `Fragment`, that means it's a `Fragment` not an `Activity`.

You should extends `FragmentActivity`.

Also for the sample map code, you can create a `MapActivity` in Android Studio as following:

[image]

And then you can put your map set up code in the `Activity`.

**EDIT**

If you wanna make a `fragment` of map, and use something like `tabs` to switch. And I tried your code, no problem with it, I think, you need to check out the `name` of fragment `layout` you inflate into. And also change the `getFragmentManager` to `getChildFragmentManager`.

**EDIT**

For your code, it will surely encounter the inflater problem when I am switching tabs, and I tried code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971284/4186942), it works, is it ok for you to change a little of you code? if so, you can try that.

I uploaded working code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/MapTab-android/tree/master). I did the `map fragment` in one of my project. Just check out 3rd tab named `UpcomingFrament`, it includes `Map fragment`

Comment: But I still want it to be swipeable afterwards, which I don't think is possible with FragmentActivity. Also it doesn't solve the problem with creating a new instance of the fragment every time you switch to it

Comment: I see what your mean, you wanna make a `fragment` of map, and use something like `tabs` to switch. And I tried your code, no problem with it, I think, you need to check out the `name` of fragment and `layout` you inflate into. And also change the `getFragmentManager` to `getChildFragmentManager`.

Comment: I can upload the success sample code I tried if you want

Comment: That woukd be anazing :)

Comment: Also, the map is also a fragment

Comment: For your code, it will surely encounter the inflater problem when I am switching tabs, and I tried code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin), it works, is it ok for you to change a little of you code? if so, you can try that.

Comment: I uploaded working code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/MapTab-android/tree/master). I did the `map fragment` in one of my project. Just check out 3rd tab named UpcomingFrament, it includes Map fragment

Comment: Thank you very much, will check it out asap

Comment: Please tell me if you have problems