# Error in TabLayout Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-tablayout

I have some problem on Implementation of fragments with TabLayout. I have 3 tabs and I hardcoded some values and googlemaps(v2). When I run program it's showing three tabs with all the harcoded values and googlemaps(v2). when I swipe from first time and second time it's working fine. But when I swipe third time It's showing Layout Inflate error. Please Help me..

Here I am attaching full code with stack Trace.

This is My First Fragment.

```
public class RequestedBookingsFragment extends Fragment {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_prefs;
    TextView tv;
    GoogleMap map;
    RecyclerView rb_recycler_view;
    List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;


    public RequestedBookingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_requested_bookings, container, false);

        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        rb_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyler_rb);


        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rb_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rb_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        intializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        return rootView;

    }

    private void intializeData() {
        pojoFromToLatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
        pojoFromToLatLngs.add(new PojoFromToLatLng("JayaMahal Office", "Koramangala", "22:22:22", "Accepted"));

    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        RecyclerCardMapAdapter adapter = new RecyclerCardMapAdapter(pojoFromToLatLngs);

        rb_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Adapter for FirstFragment:

```
public class RecyclerCardMapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerCardMapAdapter.MapBookingsHolder> {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    public class MapBookingsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        CardView main_card, sub_card;
        TextView from_address_text,to_address_text, time_tv, booking_status_tv;
        Button accept_booking_btn;


        public MapBookingsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            from_address_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.from_rb);
            to_address_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_rb);
            time_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_id_rb);
            booking_status_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.booking_status_id_rb);
            accept_booking_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookings_accept_button_rb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }


    }
    List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs;
    RecyclerCardMapAdapter(List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs1)
    {

        this.pojoFromToLatLngs=pojoFromToLatLngs1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerCardMapAdapter.MapBookingsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.requested_bookings_card_map, parent,false);
        MapBookingsHolder mbh=new MapBookingsHolder(v);
        return mbh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerCardMapAdapter.MapBookingsHolder holder, int position) {

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pojoFromToLatLngs.size();
    }
}
```

XML for FirstFragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cabbi.appstract.RequestedBookingsFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Requested Bookings"
        android:id="@+id/tv_id"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyler_rb">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my Second Fragment.

```
     public class AcceptedBookingsFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView ab_recycler_view;
    List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;


    public AcceptedBookingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accepted_bookings, container, false);
        ab_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyler_ab);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        ab_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(llm);
        ab_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        intializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void intializeData() {
        pojoFromToLatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
        pojoFromToLatLngs.add(new PojoFromToLatLng("JayaMahal Office", "Koramangala", "22:22:22", "Accepted"));

    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        AcceptingBookingAdapter adapter = new AcceptingBookingAdapter(pojoFromToLatLngs);
        //  places_type_list_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
        ab_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Adapter For Second Fragment:

```
public class AcceptingBookingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AcceptingBookingAdapter.MapBookingsHolder> {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    public class MapBookingsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        CardView main_card, sub_card;
        TextView from_address_text,to_address_text, time_tv, booking_status_tv;
        Button accept_booking_btn;


        public MapBookingsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            from_address_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.from_ab);
            to_address_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_ab);
            time_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_id_ab);
            booking_status_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.booking_status_id_ab);
            accept_booking_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookings_accepted_button_ab);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

//        @Override
//        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//            mMap = googleMap;
//
//        }
    }
    List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs;
    AcceptingBookingAdapter(List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs1)
    {

        this.pojoFromToLatLngs=pojoFromToLatLngs1;
    }

    @Override
    public AcceptingBookingAdapter.MapBookingsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.accetpted_booking_cards_map, parent,false);
        MapBookingsHolder mbh=new MapBookingsHolder(v);
        return mbh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AcceptingBookingAdapter.MapBookingsHolder holder, int position) {

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pojoFromToLatLngs.size();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cabbi.appstract.AcceptedBookingsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Accpeted Bookings"
            android:id="@+id/tv_id1"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyler_ab">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Third Fragment:

```
public class AllBookingsFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView tv;
    RecyclerView allb_recycler_view;
    List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;


    public AllBookingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_bookings, container, false);
        allb_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyler_allb);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        allb_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(llm);
        allb_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
        intializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }
    private void intializeData() {
        pojoFromToLatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
        pojoFromToLatLngs.add(new PojoFromToLatLng("JayaMahal Office", "Koramangala", "22:22:22", "Accepted"));

    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        AllBookingsAdapter adapter = new AllBookingsAdapter(pojoFromToLatLngs);
        //  places_type_list_recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
        allb_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Adapter For Third Fragment:

```
public class AllBookingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllBookingsAdapter.MapBookingsHolder> {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    public class MapBookingsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        CardView main_card, sub_card;
        TextView from_address_text,to_address_text, time_tv, booking_status_tv;
        //Button accept_booking_btn;


        public MapBookingsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            from_address_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.from_allb);
            to_address_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_allb);
            time_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_id_allb);
            booking_status_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.booking_status_id_allb);
            //accept_booking_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookings_accept_button_allb);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

//        @Override
//        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//            mMap = googleMap;
//
//        }
    }
    List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs;
    AllBookingsAdapter(List<PojoFromToLatLng> pojoFromToLatLngs1)
    {

        this.pojoFromToLatLngs=pojoFromToLatLngs1;
    }

    @Override
    public AllBookingsAdapter.MapBookingsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_bookings_card_map, parent,false);
        MapBookingsHolder mbh=new MapBookingsHolder(v);
        return mbh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AllBookingsAdapter.MapBookingsHolder holder, int position) {

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pojoFromToLatLngs.size();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cabbi.appstract.AllBookingsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All Bookings"
            android:id="@+id/tv_id2"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recyler_allb">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am inflating the below layout in all the fragments by using the AdapterClass Which I have mentioned above.

Inflating Layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_map_rb"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/maps_inside_card_rb"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="147dp"
                android:id="@+id/sub_card_for_locs_rb">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/from_rb"
                        android:text="JAYAMAHAL"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/to_rb"
                        android:text="EJIPURA"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/time_id_rb"
                            android:textSize="19dp"
                            android:text="23:55:22 15-06-2016"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/booking_status_id_rb"
                            android:text="Pending"
                            android:textSize="19dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/bookings_accept_button_rb"
                        android:text="Accept"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I created three layouts with same data but different Id's (example: for Adapter1->layout1 , for Adapter2->layout2). But here I am pasting code for one layout because all have same vaules.

I have been working on these from yesterday.. I have googled answer I have SO answers but Not able to get Solution.

Here is my Error trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.cabbi.appstract, PID: 5522
                                                                   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                       at com.cabbi.appstract.RecyclerCardMapAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerCardMapAdapter.java:57)
                                                                       at com.cabbi.appstract.RecyclerCardMapAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerCardMapAdapter.java:20)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1560)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
                                                                       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
                                                                       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
                                                                    at android.widget.L
```

Please help me..
Thanks in advance..............

Comment: please provide the code you are working on and possibly the error message.

Comment: Since you don't get any error by second swipe, your tabs are created correctly (by second swipe the third Tab is also created). So one reason would be the incorrect number of Tabs. My suggestion: in android studio make a new project and "Add a Tabbed Activity". Then change it to match your project. If you get more detail maybe I could better help.

Comment: @Behy Thanks for quick reply.. I have pasted my full code here.. Please Tell me where I am doing mistake

Comment: but the trace doesn't show any Error. Please run it until you get error then send the trace

Comment: @Behy This is the error I pasted above  **Process: com.cabbi.appstract, PID: 5522
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapview is causing troble you should use com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
in place of fragment in xml.

Read more here

[Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin)

Comment: Sorry Madhu, I wanted to write better answer but I am in a city bus.